# Integrating skype for business into my web app

Tags: msdn, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have a web app where if a user signs up, a notification is sent to the slack channel. I want to achieve the same thing in skype for business but I cant find any good resources. Will it be possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That isn´t so easy to answer as Skype for Business (=SfB) is a very complex product and you didn´t outlined a real use case (e.g. will a group of persons addressed or only one person, what should happen if nobody is in, ...).

As a starting point you could build something on your own via the [Skype for Business Web SDK](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk) which fits your needs. If you search for that via Google you can find various article which gives you some examples which can be adjusted (for example [here](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-run-the-new-skype-web-sdk-online-samples/)).

You might also wish to try to find a old version from the "[Lync Presence & Chat Widget](https://lyncwidget.codeplex.com/)" as it became a commercial product.

If you wish to get a commercial "plugin" you can try to use:

- [OrbitOne - Lync Presence & Chat Widgets](http://blog.orbitone.com/post/Lync-Presence-Chat-Widgets) [see here](http://blog.orbitone.com/post/Lync-Presence-Chat-Widgets) (Demo [here](http://blog.orbitone.com/post/Lync-Presence-and-Chat-Widget))
- [Vytru Live Web Chat Widget](http://www.vytru.com/skype-web-chat-widget.html) for Lync/Skype for Business
- [Enabling WebChat](http://enablingwebchat.com/)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that when a user sign up in my web app, a notification is sent to a group (channel in the case of slack). So ya a group in skype for business.
Thanks for the link, though I have already checked it, i will check it again to see if i have missed anything

Comment: i have integrated slack, fb workplace and in those platforms I could achieve my requirements by just using this webhook and graph api, access token and wallah, my bot can post to the channel and the grp.

Comment: i was researching microsoft team and I could post into its group by using its webhook, is there anything similar for skype for business?